Why mesh not following bone in blender, And why Mesh keep duplicating when Bone is Moving?
I don't know if it's a bug or not, but when i rigged the MetaHuman Rig to the character, it keeps duplicating the mesh when the Bone is Moving, and won't follow where the bone is going either ‍♂️


Hello, if it's duplicating the mesh it means that the mesh has been duplicated, maybe share your file so that we can check

Hey,  i haven't duplicated the mesh before so i don't why that's happening

how do i import files on this website again?

Use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or another platform like workupload

So i just WorkUpload, here it is:  https://workupload.com/file/sg6p7Gd9BBb

It's just that some hair strands have not been assigned to any vertex group, select the whole mesh in Edit mode and assign to the vertex group called Head and you're good:


Alright let me try, BRB

Hey it works! Thanks!
